# Cry me a River?

Tags: riddle

I am born everyday, and always awake

Some times I am plenty, and some times none

I don't have feet and I travel light

People, few happy, are on me

And day by day, they want me more

To put the load they don't want to carry

I can't see you as I have no eyes

But cry I do, day or night

For, I am, you see loud

Comment: This is my first time forming a riddle. Excuse the sentences if they don't fit in.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Is it:

> Clouds

I am born everyday, and always awake.

> Everyday with sunrise the sky is born and almost always there are clouds in it. But, clouds are around always, and always moving.

Some times I am plenty, and some times none.

> Sometimes there are lots of clouds, sometimes few.

I don't have feet and I travel light.

> Clouds have no feet, but are "fluffy and light."

People, few happy, are on me.

> Happy people are sometimes said to be on "cloud" 9.  Other times we hear about "storm clouds" when people are mad.

And day by day, they want me more.

> Depending on the season, people often want clouds. In the winter for snow and the other activities. In summer for shade.

To put the load they don't want to carry.

> Here I'm a little short. Maybe, we wish our burdens were light as a cloud? From the OP, refers to storing data on the cloud.

I can't see you as I have no eyes.

> Clouds have no eyes, and technically can't see.

But cry I do, day or night.

> Rain comes day or night.

For, I am, you see loud.

> Lightning in the sky can be very loud.  Or (thanks to Rand for pointing this out), see loud, "c" loud, cloud.

Comment: Nice answer! Most of your explanations seem to fit "clouds" better than "the sky" though.

Comment: True. Maybe I should refine that.

Comment: Look at the last line!! **See loud**. You've got it.

Comment: Haha. Very nice. I've used "see" enough times you'd think I'd "c" that.

Comment: @AggieKidd It's the correct answer! Yes, "See Loud" = "Cloud" was the clue I was indicating. In these lines, "And day by day, they want me more. To put the load they don't want to carry.", I was indicating the Cloud that people want to store their data on. But yes, you got it!

Comment: Thanks to Rand for directing me towards cloud and away from sky.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe it's

> MONEY.

*I am born everyday, and awake always*

> Money is always being printed, and ATM cash machines are always 'awake' and ready to be used.

*Some times, I am plenty, and some times none*

> Some people have plenty of money, and some have none.

*I don't have feet, and I travel light*

> Money has no feet, and it's quite light for being so valuable: you can fit a million pounds/dollars/euros in a suitcase (or so I've heard).

*People, few happy, are on me*

> Coins and notes often bear pictures of people's faces.

*And day by day, they want me more*

> People always want more money.

*To put the load, they don't want to carry*

> It's lighter and easier to handle than the material goods it 'represents'.

*Since I can't see you as I have no eyes*

> Indeed.

*And cry I do, day or night*

*For, I am, you see loud*

> Not sure about these lines.

Comment: This is a very good answer, but not what I was looking for. If I would not have put the last two lines, your answer would have been perfect. But the last two lines hold a major clue.